# Search function in document libraries not working in the UAT environment of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

SharePoint 2013 search is configured properly in the UAT and QA/Development environment and its also returning the result. 
However, the search function of document libraries not working in the UAT environment, whereas, work in QA or development environment. Are we missing any steps?

I have redindexing the library: library Settings -> Advanced settings -> Reindex library

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions to troubleshoot this.

1. Can you see any error in the ULS logs when you type in the search box and hit enter?
2. Run the full crawl in central admin and check if there are any errors.
3. Isolate the issue for one library. Click on the `Reindex Document Library` button in the library settings -> Advanced Settings and make sure the search function works. Make sure `Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?` is set to `Yes`
   [image]